# Why can I not import from a module in memory

Tags: python, python-2.7, module

I can do `import module as md`

I can do `import module.submodule as smd`

So why can't I do either of the following?

```
import module as md
import md.submodule as smd
```

or

```
import module as md
from md import submodule as smd
```

Asked differently: why do I have to use the long name, rather than the name I gave it?

After the first line, `md` should just be a first-class object in memory. Why was the decision made not to let me import from this object? (Especially considering the code "reads" as if `module` is already available in memory at the start - the Python guys explicitly chose for this syntax as opposed to something like `md = import("module")`)

Comment: Because the `.` in the long name actually represents the current operating system's pathname component separator (`os.sep`), so a compound name is really just a platform independent way of specifying the path to a module or submodule — which must actually exist in the file-system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just by having a look at what the module `dis` and its [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-IMPORT_NAME) say might clarify what happens in background.

```
>>> def g():
...   import numpy as np
... 
>>> def h():
...   import np.ma as ma # note: np is not defined!
... 
>>> dis.dis(g)
  2       0 LOAD_CONST               1 (-1)
          3 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
          6 IMPORT_NAME              0 (numpy)
          9 STORE_FAST               0 (np)
         12 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
         15 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis.dis(h)
  2       0 LOAD_CONST               1 (-1)
          3 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
          6 IMPORT_NAME              0 (np.ma)
          9 STORE_FAST               0 (np)
         12 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
         15 RETURN_VALUE
```

To quote the docs, [IMPORT_NAME](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-IMPORT_NAME) means:

> Imports the module co_names[namei]. TOS and TOS1 are popped and provide the fromlist and level arguments of `__import__()`. The module object is pushed onto the stack. The current namespace is not affected: for a proper import statement, a subsequent STORE_FAST instruction modifies the namespace.

(TOS and TOS1 are the top-of-Stack and the the second top-most stack item.)

Therefore, I would say that the reason it doesn't work is that the `import` statement works if and only if the token you pass is really a module name (not an object), as this will be passed to the `__import__` function, which requires a module name, not a reference/variable/whatever.

More information about how this works can be found on the [`__import__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__) documentation page.

Answer (score 3):

Because `md` may be an existing module, and since python is permissive, it will let you replace its name but you can still import it whenever you want, example:

```
>> import urllib2 as json
```

This will work, even though json is a real module and could be imported, what if you wanted to import it afterwards ?

so when you will check json in this case

```
>> json
>> <module 'urllib2' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.pyc'>
```

it is pointed to urllib2 but you can still import submodules of real json:

```
>> from json import tool as tl
```

json will remain the same as before, which is urllib2.
but you can get it back

```
>> import json
>> <module 'json' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.pyc'>
```

So to answer your question, it is probably a way to make it still accessible to get modules from your supposed alias ( if it is a name of a real module ).